# Online math TeX files not rendering equal sign correctly

Tags: math-mode

I have recently noticed that when I try to visualize a .pdf file with math through my browser (FireFox 43.0.4 on Windows XP), the equal sign in math mode is not rendered correctly. It is instead substituted by something that looks like a dash.[image]
Those dash looking symbols after the first G and after g should both be equal (=) signs. What is going on?

I am unsure about what tags to use or if this is a proper question on this stackexchange site since this is my first post, so feel free to edit this accordingly.

Comment: I'm not aware of any browser plugin that can display dvi, what are you using?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Funny; now that I look better at it, it's a .pdf named (name).dvi. I'll edit to make it clear!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you posted a small (few line) _complete_ document that reproduces the problem (use the `{}` button in the editor for code sections) If you mean are using one of the online systems such as sharelatex you could also point to an instance on the web that shows the problem, but a local document added to the question is always helpful for people to run/debug.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Maybe I am not explaining myself clearly; I did not write the document myself. This happens on every document found online that I access through my browser (e.g. University Homework), which can correctly be seen by other machines. Should I try writing a short document myself and using my browser to open it?

Comment: well if the problem only occurs with non-reproducible files on a closed network, you are more likely to get help from your university help desk than from a global forum:-) If you can reproduce the problem with a file that you can post here there is a chance someone might be able to help.

Comment: also what happens if you download the online file and then view it with a local pdf viewer such as acrobat, does it have the same problem?

Comment: Do you know whether the font is properly embedded into the pdf? Have you tested by just downloading the pdf and viewing the pdf in Adobe Reader to test if it is pdf.js that is displaying wrong (if it is report it to the pdf.js people, it is not the first time that build in pdf viewer have has rendering issues)

Comment: Downloading the pdf gives no problems at all: it works fine. Now that I notice, it seems this problem happens only with pdfs related to my university's domain: quite weird. I had not thought this could be the issue. It only happens on one of my computers, though.

Comment: I fear we have to close this as off topic as it seems that it is (somehow) a local pdf viewing issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because local pdf viewer issue

Comment: Okay. Sorry to bother and thanks for the insight!